# Can you bind activerecord callbacks outside of a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm positive you can I just can't find how to do so in the docs. For instance I want to bind an "after_create" hook across multiple models in a single location outside of all the models. Would I do so by extending activerecorde base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use observers, http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

or you could extend `ActiveRecord::Base` if you want to do it for every model ever.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include [ActiveModel::Callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Callbacks).